# User root while Group is root but Changing Ownership from /dev/ Ultimately

Tags: linux, permissions, users, group

Okay...so I have used chown and chmod as directed by many tutorials to access some `/dev/` files for peripherals.

The chown and chmod does not make it past a reboot. This is okay. The issue I am seeing has to do with not being able to manipulate the `/dev/` directory files, for instance `gpio` and/or `i2c`, with success even after using chmod and/or chown...

So, I set my naming scheme for the current user and then set my group for that user but still without access to my files. I am using a embedded computer with a Specification that dictates files be filled in `/dev/bone/` for some peripheral files like `pwm`, `uart`, and `i2c`.

Is `/dev/` special in that controlling files from within `/dev/` cannot be affected by commanding permissions and user:group additions w/ chown and chmod?

Still trying to wrap my education around the build in /dev/ while not using /sys/class/gpio/ and/or /sys/class/pwm/.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/manage-permissions is where I started to learn about chown and chmod for changing user:group and setting ownership. Still nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/dev/` directory tree is generated anew when the system boots. After all, you may have added/removed hardware.

Many device access problems are permission problems, and can be resolved through group membership changes.

You can find the device name by watching `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device. OR `ls -1 -l /dev >dev.before`, connect the device, wait 10 seconds, `ls -1 -l /dev >dev.after;diff dev.{before,after}`.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/YourDevice"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: Thank you. I will sign in soon and return service.

Comment: Okay, so I am using WSL2 on Windows 11 but the target is a Linux based controller. I usually ssh and sftp to/from the board from WSL2. I am not sure what steps are taken to go that far just yet. I will have to reconvene on a Bookworm Distro soon. Until then, sorry it is takin me so long: @waltinator

Comment: Unix&Linux  is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you have new information on your original question, [edit] the question and add it. If you have a new question, [ask] it. Do not try to start conversations in a Comment.

Comment: Okay. You got it.